# Invoking Data Protection API from within a CustomAction

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.5

I am trying to run some unmanaged code from a C# ca within WIX. I have a wrapper around the [CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261(v=vs.85).aspx%00) function, this code works fine if run from an admin prompt. I have scheduled the ca as deferred hoping it would run during the elevated session however it fails in this context.

The scheduling is as follows:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetCustomActionDataValue" Property="EncryptValues" Value="foo=bar;...;" />
<CustomAction Id="EncryptValues" BinaryKey="InstallerCustomAction.CA.dll" DllEntry="EncryptValues" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" HideTarget="no" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetCustomActionDataValue" After="InstallFiles" />
  <Custom Action="EncryptValues" After="SetCustomActionDataValue" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

What needs to be done to allow something like this to run during the installer, preferably after the files and registry entries are committed to the system?

Comment: Check execution sequence in ORCA and run your CA after last custom action before InstallFinlize. InstallFinilize is the last customAction that run as deferred.

Comment: That did not seem to help. Apparently there is something about the windows installer environment in both the immediate and deferred stages that prevents the DPAPI code from running. The same code runs fine when invoked from a plain console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any logging in your CA?  Can you confirm that your CustomActionData made it over?

One thing you might try is to wire this up as a simple console app and use PSExec to invoke a cmd.exe prompt as SYSTEM.

I've never used this API but the comment "Typically, only a user with the same logon credential as the user who encrypted the data can decrypt the data."  makes me think that this might not run well as SYSTEM.    This article seems to confirm that.  http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx

FWIW, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but I'd consider moving it from the installer to the application if possible.  Installers are generally best kept simple and reliable.

Comment: Yes I have logging. The CA enters the context of the alternate user with code similar to [Impersonation code in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joncole/archive/2009/09/21/impersonation-code-in-c.aspx), I log the new user, it then attempts to leverage the DPAPI code. Using process monitor, I can not see an obvious issue, the encryption simply fails. I could move this portion out, however the installer has dialog's that query all the required runtime configuration (its a service) and leaving out this step would be less than ideal.

Comment: Many Windows Installer experts believe that configuration data should be left out of the installer and handled on first run.  In the case of a service you could start the service in a quiescent mode and then start processing the workflow after the configuration data is initialized.